# Can ridge and robust regressions be used when the dependent variable is categorical?

Tags: categorical-data, robust, ridge-regression

I was wondering if we can use Ridge and Robust regressions when the dependent variable is categorical.

Answer (score 2):

When the dependent variable is categorical, perhaps you can state the problem as classification. In this case, logistic regression is one of the techniques which can be used.

Ridge regularization carries very naturally to logistic regression. See, for example [Ridge Logistic Regression For Preventing Overfitting](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/303/lec/lec8/ridge.pdf). Incidentally, l1 normalization can additionally be used, e.g., in the [elastic net algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) for logistic regression.

As for robust (in the outlier sense) methods, see [Robust Logistic Regression And Classification](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5515-robust-logistic-regression-and-classification.pdf).